# Can I use old Pentax lenses on newer Pentax DSLRs?

Tags: lens, pentax, old-lenses, compatibility, k-mount

Can I use old Pentax lenses from the film days on the newer Pentax DSLRs?

Are there any caveats or exceptions? Are adapters or modifications needed?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, all Pentax DSLRs accept all K-mount lenses.  This includes autofocusing (if applicable), focus confirmation, metering, IS, etc.

The oldest two series, K and M series ([database](http://www.pentaxforums.com/lensreviews/)), do not have aperture contacts, and thus do not work with Av and Tv mode.  Instead, you'll have to use M mode, but you will get meter readings.  It can also suggest a shutter speed if you push the +/- or green button (depending on camera model and settings).  Metering on these digital SLRs tends to be noticeably more inconsistent than on on the film SLRs they were designed for.  These two series do not get matrix metering, just center-weighted and spot, but do get focus-trap.

There is a rare breed of K-mount that Ricoh used, called "KR" mount.  They have an extra pin which will get stuck if it is not [removed](http://www.theatreofnoise.com/2008/05/ricoh-lenses-on-pentax-cameras-ricoh.html).

You can also get a M42-PK adapter and use the endless supply of great cheap screwmount lenses available at ebay, pawnshops, etc.  They will have focus confirmation, IS, center/spot metering, and can actually use Av mode as they will stop down with the aperture ring.

Comment: That pretty much sums it up. I haunt Craigslist looking for Pentax glass all the time, great deals on older, and top notch, lenses.

Comment: Thanks. So to sum up, there are basically 3 different mounts? (K, M, and KR)? I can use K & M directly (some may have to be manual exposure), but KR needs an extra pin removed (DIY removal possible?).

Comment: For the screw mount lenses, are they like any kind of screw mount? or do they have to be Pentax screw mount?

Comment: @Johannes: K, M, F, FA, DA are lens series.  They are all K-mount.

KR is a K-mount with an extra pin, DIY necessary.  I have not used any KR lenses.  

All "screwmounts" people refer to are are M42 with the exception of rangefinder ones, which should be labeled as M39 or LTM (Leica).  Some russian lenses from Zenit cameras are this type.  T-mounts are also screw-type but should be labeled appropriately.

Comment: I find the "green button" meter readings to be annoying compared to using the same lenses with the continuous needle meter of my K1000. I think this should be mentioned more strongly.

Comment: On the istDS the button for shutter speed suggestion is the AE-L button; and you get meter reading when stopping down.

Answer (score 8):

There is a great summary of K-mount features at [Bojidar Dimitor's page](http://www.bdimitrov.de/kmp/technology/summary/index.html). You should look for the "crippled" KAF2 body.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the K-mount still used on most current Pentax DSLRs (except medium format, like 645D or 645Z), there were **Pentax 645** and **Pentax 67**, both are medium formats. Those lenses are quite heavy and you'll need an expensive adapter for them.

Before K-mount, Pentax used a screw-mount called **M42**; you'll need an adapter to use an M42 lens. There's a huge selection of those lenses available. Adapters are not too expensive, available from both Pentax and third parties. With third party adapters, make sure it is of the thin makes-even-surface-with-bayonet design - the ones that have a metal layer over bayonet will not let your M42 lens focus to infinity. I have three different adapters, and Pentax original one is clearly the best one as it allows focusing to infinity and the lens fixes with correct right side up.

You'll want to have either a *preset* lens, or one with fully manual diaphragm; your dSLR cannot trigger aperture pin on an M42 lens, sometimes the pin can be glued though.

With some non-Pentax M42 lens (especially wider or faster ones), you need to check that the rear element does not **protrude** enough to get in mirror's way. Same warning for **aperture pins** used on some designs evolved from M42 (your dSLR will not use the pin to stop down the lens).

Also, some designs have protrusions on back that will get stuck on auto-focus coupler or screw heads on the rim of bayonet, thus getting **stuck** on the camera. Always check for possible problems before screwing on an M42 lens for first time.

I hope  this didn't sound too intimidating, I've been using 4 different M42 lenses with no significant problems.

Technically, **M37** screw-mount could also be attributed to Pentax, although back then the company was named Asahi Optical Corporation. Those lenses are even older than M42 lenses, and much more of a rarity nowadays. The adapters are scarce, too; most likely you'd find M37-to-M42 adapter with which you'd then also need to use an M42-to-K-mount adapter.

Answer (score 2):

The Pentax-M 50mm f2 lens works out of the box on my Pentax K-x, metering + aperture. However precise focusing is only possible via life view and the image quality is significantly lower than the kit lens.

A film era Sigma PK zoom that I tried could not be mounted because it was protruding too far inside the Pentax K-x body, it could presumably have been fixed with a metal file.

In general I found all consumer film era lenses I tried to be inferior to the kit lenses in terms of image quality (and of course handling).

Some old pro lenses provide similar or better image quality and some old telephoto lenses have more reach than the 50-200mm kit lens. For long telephoto lenses with a narrow field of view manual focus through the view finder works sufficiently precise.

Comment: Have you tried the 50mm f/1.7? It's much, much nicer than the f/2.

Comment: I have not tried the pentax 50mm f/1.7, but I have tried the Yashinon-DS 50mm f/1.7. The Yashinon is better than the Pentax 50mm f/2 but suffers from a yellow tint due to radioactive degradation of the glass. I still prefer the kit lens although the shallow depth of field of the Yashinon is nice.